# Google cloud Argocd failed to allocate for range 0: no IP addresses available

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

i tried to install argocd with helm (and also with deployment) each time a have this error on pods :"failed to allocate for range 0: no IP addresses available "
thanks for your help

Comment: >To resolve this issue, upgrade your cluster and node pools to GKE version 1.18.17 or later.  or `kubectl drain NODE --force` https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#error_failed_to_allocate_for_range_0_no_ip_addresses_in_range_set

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer;
but doesn't fix the problem...